# Ray Tracing and Rotations

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, rotation

I would like to be able to write the matrix operations to be able to define the first arm of the picture below. How can I do that?

I have learned beam physics, have read Siegman's Lasers, if that helps out.

[image]

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you call the "first arm of the picture below". Could it be that something didn't translate well from your native language? Can you explain what you have tried and what you want to achieve?

Comment: I think you are asking the matrix for a 45 degree rotation within Ray transfer matrix analysis https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis ?

Comment: @Floris: it's not a language issue - I am fluent in both English and my native langue. What I mean is the ray tracing from the source beam the second mirror - its ok if you disregard the lens. 

I have been trying to map the effect of misalignment on mirror's orientations to beam position. I am trying to use ray tracing formalism - using both Siegman's Lasers and Marix and Introduction to Matrix Methods in Optics. 

I have already tested this in beam line shown above and also using ZEMAX. I am trying to use formalism from first principle to map changes in angles mapping to changes in pos.